# How to add a fault handler to the entire state machine workflow?

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, error-handling, state-machine

I have a running **Site** workflow. If the workflow fails for whatever reason, I want to log it in a special way so that I don't have to struggle with the ULS log to figure out what went wrong.

How can I add a general (catch all) fault handler to a Site state machine workflow (all examples I find are for sequential workflows)?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [SPWorkflowEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventreceiver.aspx). If I'm not wrong the [WorkflowPostponed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventreceiver.workflowpostponed.aspx) is invoked when the exception is thrown. In this method you have access to the [SPWorkflowEventProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventproperties_members.aspx). There are ErrorException and ErrorMessage properties that can be used by you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but somehow I have the feeling that this is sort of a workaround, or is it not?

Comment: It is not a workaround. There is a question about this in the [Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Application Development exam](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?id=70-573).

Comment: And that's the only way? You can't add fault handlers to a state machine workflow?

Comment: As I know each state of the workflow has own fault handler. You can try to create activity that is handle the exception and add it to this fault handler. To see it you can click Fault Handler context menu item.

Comment: Sorry.. each event driven activity has "view fault handlers" option, not a state.

Comment: From what I see this applies only for list based workflows. **Mine is a site workflow.** Can that work?